# how to select expand plus icon in react-sortable-tree

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-sortable-tree

I am using react-sortable-tree how to select that expand plus icon in this package because it provide only

```
    `<SortableTree
          treeData={this.state.treeData}
          onChange={treeData => this.setState({ treeData })}
    />`
```

[That red box plus icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvIgV.png)

when i click inspect it has a class name "rst__expandButton" how can select that class and write condition for it

i tried like this

```
`const data = document.getElementsByClassName(rst__expandButton)

  const myFunction(()=>{
      data.onclick(function)
  })
  myFunction()
return(
   <SortableTree
       treeData={this.state.treeData}
       onChange={treeData => this.setState({ treeData })}
/>
)`
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName method returns an array. if that array is not empty you should choose the element inside of that array like data[0]

Answer (score 0):

**react-sortable-tree** has **onVisibilityToggle** prop.

Called after children nodes collapsed or expanded:

```
({ treeData: object[], node: object, expanded: bool, path: number[] or string[] }): void
```

This prop gives you node expanded or collapsed info with node detail. Then you can write the condition.

```
<SortableTree
      treeData={this.state.treeData}
      onChange={treeData => this.setState({ treeData })}
      onVisibilityToggle={toggleData => console.log(toggleData)}
/>
```